# How to combine mulitiple LINQ to objects requests into single one

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I would like to rewrite GetCurrentAuction into single LINQ request:

```
private AuctionInfo GetCurrentAuction()
    {
        var auctions = Auctions.List().ToList();
        var liveAuction = auctions
            .Where(AuctionIsLive)
            .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (liveAuction != null)
        {
            return liveAuction;
        }

        var openAuction = auctions
            .Where(AuctionIsOpen)
            .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (openAuction != null)
        {
            return openAuction;
        }

        // next upcoming auction
        return auctions
            .Where(a => a.StartDate >= DateTime.UtcNow)
            .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private bool AuctionIsLive(AuctionInfo auction)
    {
        // WorkflowStage is int
        return auction.WorkflowStage == LIVE_WORKFLOW_STAGE;
    }

    private bool AuctionIsOpen(AuctionInfo auction)
    {
        return auction.WorkflowStage == OPEN_WORKFLOW_STAGE;
    }
```

Could someone suggest how to achieve this? It looks like using `auctions.GroupBy(a => a.WorkflowStage)` doesn't bring me closer to the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if your existing code is necessarily correct. You do searches for the earliest (of all history) "Live" auction and earliest "Open" auction, and abort if you don't find both. Then you do a third search for the earliest _upcoming/future_ auction, regardless of it being "Live" or "Open" (essentially ignoring your previous searches for "Live" and "Open") and return it. Is this correct?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair the only way I will execute "upcoming auction" query if there are no any live or open auction

Comment: In best case scenario I execute only single query( found live auction and return it), in worst 3

Comment: -1 You need to tell use what type of Linq you are using? Linq to SQL, to EF, to Objects etc? Please tag which type you are using.

Comment: And what does `Auctions.List()` return? I think you're main problem is that you drag all auctions into memory. That should be dealt with first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indicate preference by ordering them - something like:

```
return
  Auctions.List().ToList()  //--> ToList() not needed here?
  .Where
  ( a =>
    AuctionIsLive(a) ||
    AuctionIsOpen(a) ||
    a.StartDate >= DateTime.UtcNow
  )
  .OrderBy
  ( a => 
    AuctionIsLive( a ) ? 0 :
    AuctionIsOpen( a ) ? 1 : 2
  )
  .ThenBy( a => a.StartDate )
  .FirstOrDefaut();
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but you're leaving out the logic that gets the next upcoming auction if there are no live or open auctions. I'd add `.ThenBy(a => a.StartDate)` right before `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Dustin Cleveland - Actually - I had that (but slightly different), but I took it out because the where clause only included live, open or in-the-future - so, live is favored, followed by open, followed by (only) items-in-the-future.

Comment: @Clay But the list of auctions could be unordered and then we are not getting earliest action first

Comment: @OleksiiAza - I see now - yes!  Have edited answer - thanks to both you and Dustin

Answer (score 2):

You can use very usefull ?? ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx ) operator and achive this:

```
        var result = auctions.Where(AuctionIsLive).OrderBy( x => x.StartDate).FirstOrDefault() ?? 
            auctions.Where(AuctionIsOpen).OrderBy( x => x.StartDate).FirstOrDefault() ??
            auctions.Where(a => a.StartDate >= DateTime.UtcNow).OrderBy(a => a.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();

        return result;
```

Comment: @funkyCats it's definitely improve readability, thanks. But in worst scenario it steal executes multiple queries.

Comment: @EugeneSafronov please try this one:          `var result2 =
                auctions.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).FirstOrDefault(x => x.WorkflowStage == LIVE_WORKFLOW_STAGE
                                                                       || x.WorkflowStage == OPEN_WORKFLOW_STAGE
                                                                       || x.StartDate >= DateTime.UtcNow);`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the datasource and LINQ provider you're using.
For example, if you use LINQ to SQL the preferent way of doing it would be using `Expressions` to save your memory and end up with the answer simular to @fankyCatz's:

```
return Auctions.Where(a => a.WorkflowStage == LIVE_WORKFLOW_STAGE).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).FirstOrDefault() ??
        Auctions.Where(a => a.WorkflowStage == OPEN_WORKFLOW_STAGE).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).FirstOrDefault() ??
        Auctions.Where(a => a.StartDate >= DateTime.UtcNow).OrderBy(a => a.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, using only LINQ to Objects I would end up with the answer simular to @Clay's one, just would improve readability with mapping:

```
public static Dictionary<int, Func<AuctionInfo, bool>> Presedence = 
            new Dictionary<int, Func<AuctionInfo, bool>>
{
    { 0, a => a.WorkflowStage == LIVE_WORKFLOW_STAGE },
    { 1, a => a.WorkflowStage == OPEN_WORKFLOW_STAGE },
    { 2, a => a.StartDate >= DateTime.UtcNow },
};

//in your GetCurrentAuction()
return Auctions.Where(a => Presedence.Any(p => p.Value(a)))
                .OrderBy(a => Presedence.First(p => p.Value(a)).Key)
                .ThenBy(a => a.StartDate)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```